# How do I configure a class created then moved into a package

Tags: java

I made some classes outside a package, then i drag and dropped the classes into a package folder. How do I properly configure it? 
Example 2 classes:

A.java and B.java

```
public class A{
 private int a;
  public A(){
  a = 10
  }
  public int getA(){
     return a;
  }
 }
```

lets assume A.java was created outside the package then was moved to the package folder.
B.java

```
public class B{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   int num;
   A aFile;
   aFile = new A();
   num = aFile.getA();
  }
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't care whether you created the files somewhere else, or in their current location...

Comment: Just add `package` statement at the start of code to correctly specify the package your class is in. Since `A` is in same package as `B`, you'll need not import A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you must declare the package. So your first step is to add the `package` statement like so:

```
package a_package_name;
public class A{
    private int a;
    public A(){
        a = 10
    }
    public int getA(){
       return a;
    }
 }
```

Then B would be:

```
package b_package_name;
public class B{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int num;
       A aFile;
       aFile = new A();
       num = aFile.getA();
   }
}
```

Remember to add imports if necessary!